# How can I check for cycles when working with a list of edges?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have a list of edges already sorted by weight (assume each edge has a weight that is either the same or greater than the previous edge), such as [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']], how can I create a new list which represents a minimum spanning tree where no cycles exist? So in this case I would go down my original list and continue adding edges unless they make a cycle or until every vertex is hit. Also, I am not allowed to use imports for this problem. I'm thinking that recursion might be the answer, but I'm not entirely sure.

So with the example above, I would want the final list to have [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]. The list does not include ['C', 'D'] because that would create a cycle.

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm of course. Or Prim's. Have you tried implementing either of these?

Comment: I'm actually trying to mimic Kruskal's algorithm, but I'm just not sure how to check for cycles when adding edges to the final list of edges that my function will return.

Comment: I think the best way to work with graphs in plain python is via a dict-of-lists, where the keys are the nodes, and the values are a list of neighbors to that node, e.g. `{'A': ['D', 'B'], ...}`. Each time you add an edge, you add the nodes on both side of the edge and add the neighbor for each node. A "cycle" in this case would just be when both the left and right node of the edge are already in the graph. And since the graph is a dict, this is just two constant-time `in` operations.

Comment: You could imagine a `for node1, node2 in edges:` and then an `if node1 in graph and node2 in graph: continue` to skip that edge. Otherwise `graph[node1].append(node2)` and `graph[node2].append(node1)`. You can use a `defaultdict` so that you can always `append()` to a list without having to create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [networkx](https://pypi.org/project/networkx). It implements the relevant algorithms.

Comment: @a_guest yea but OP specified no imports. Edit: OP, does this mean no *standard library* imports as well? Or just no external dependencies?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds In any case the implementation can serve as a source of inspiration or insight.

Comment: In the example that you gave, edges is a dictionary and graph is the list that will be returned, right?

Comment: No standard library imports either